# Java Generics Refactoring and Ambiguity

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

I have an old untyped class pre Java1.5 and need to refactor it using Java Generics to get more type security in the code.

Old Code looks like this:

```
class Foo { 
  void setInput(Object input) {...}
}
```

Now this *input* could be some object but it may also be an array, nasty stuff. Making a generic version of it seems not to be trivial, I tried:

```
class Foo<E> {
  void setInput(E input) {...}
  void setInput(E[] input) {...}
}
```

The problem is that this is ambiguous for example for calls:

```
Foo f = Foo<SomeClassyClass>();
f.setInput(null);
```

Is there some good solution to this problem or do I need to take a completely other approach?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of ambiguity is not new to generics but can always happen with overloaded methods. You have to cast the `null`:

```
Foo<String> f = new Foo<String>();

f.setInput((String[]) null);
f.setInput((String) null);
```

Comment: A much better way to fix is to prefer not to overload. (Also `List<>` is your friend; `[]` less so.)

Comment: The way the new code looks it seems to me that the old `setInput` probably did the distinction whether it got a single element or an array via `instanceof` which is far worse than overloading (but this is just a guess on my side). I always find it nice when some method that takes some `Collection` also is overloaded with a method that takes a single element and uses `Collections.singletonList()` (or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you can do:

```
Foo<SomeClassyClass> f = new Foo<SomeClassyClass>();
f.setInput((SomeClassyClass)null);
```

or:

```
Foo<SomeClassyClass> f = new Foo<SomeClassyClass>();
f.setInput((SomeClassyClass[])null);
```

To solve the ambiguïty.